# A table's <tr> cannot have border, it seems, for IE 7, but I don't see in books that talks about <tr> border either?

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-7

This one will show border for Chrome, FF, IE 8 and 9, but it won't show a border for IE 7.

> http://jsfiddle.net/y7HWr/10/

(which is to have a border for `<tr>`).  So I think probably IE 7 is at fault?  Even though I don't see books talking about borders for `<tr>` elements (they talk about for `<tr>` elements usually), but really it should apply to most any elements?  (maybe except elements that doesn't make sense to have borders, such as `<meta>` or `<script>` or `<style>`... otherwise most other elements should be able to have a border?

Instead of marking each `<td>` to be the class `.end-of-category`, I change it this way so that it works with IE 7... any alternatives or other ideas?

```
tr.end-of-category td { border: 6px solid #000 }
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? By the way, the border the way you did it also doesn't work in IE6.

Comment: it is to put a "separation line", such as for a table's main divisions (within the table), such as the "nutrition labels" you see on the side of the boxes in supermarket (google "nutrition label" images)

Answer (score 1):

```
table { border-collapse: collapse }
table .end-of-category td { border-bottom: 6px solid #000 }
```

The above should work, or at least achieve the same if you've only got one border involved - I think it's how the different browser handle border-collapsing, but then again maybe it's just IE

---

**Update:** yes, it's IE7

using the `separate` border model (default) means no-one renders the border on the `tr`

```
table { }
table .end-of-category { border-bottom: 6px solid #000 }
```

So it seems like, IE7 had a difference of opinion again LOL!

---

Using the collapsed table borders it would be very unlikely an effect couldn't be achieved using the `TD` borders instead, but still!

Answer (score 0):

```
.end-of-category td { border: 6px solid #000 }
```

Works in IE7 and IE6.